# why one kafka node's data dir size is very big

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera-cdh

One kafka broker is down in our dev cluster.

I found that the down node's kafka data dir is very big and bigger than other nodes.

- Down node:

`[root@5 ~]# cd /var/local/kafka/
[root@5 kafka]# du --max-depth=1 -ch|sort -hr
100G    total
100G    ./data
100G
[root@5 data]# ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-1
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-10
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-11
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-12
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-13
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-14
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-15
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-16
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-17
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-18
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-19
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-2
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-20
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-21
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-22
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-23
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-24
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-25
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-26
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-27
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-28
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-29
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-3
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-30
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-31
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-32
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-33
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-34
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-35
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-36
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-37
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-38
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-39
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-4
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-40
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-41
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-42
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 11:25 __consumer_offsets-43
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-44
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-45
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-46
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  1 13:26 __consumer_offsets-47
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-48
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-49
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 11:25 __consumer_offsets-5
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-6
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-7
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 11:25 __consumer_offsets-8
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka   70 Apr  6 14:00 __consumer_offsets-9
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka 8192 Apr  6 14:00 appTimeLog-0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka    0 Apr  1 11:32 cleaner-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka   55 Apr  1 11:34 meta.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 1218 Apr  6 01:34 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 1224 Apr  6 01:35 replication-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka    0 Apr  6 01:35 replication-offset-checkpoint.tmp`

And here are some error role log (not in asc time order)

`...
2017-04-01 11:38:06,357 ERROR kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread: [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-95], Error for partition [__consumer_offsets,19] to broker 95:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.
...
2017-04-01 11:38:30,324 ERROR state.change.logger: Broker 97 received LeaderAndIsrRequest with correlation id 1 from controller 96 epoch 1 for partition [__consumer_offsets,20] but cannot become follower since the new leader 96 is unavailable.
...
2017-04-01 11:38:36,352 ERROR kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread: [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-96], Error for partition [__consumer_offsets,16] to broker 96:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.
...
2017-04-06 11:25:36,079 WARN kafka.log.Log: Found a corrupted index file, /var/local/kafka/data/__consumer_offsets-18/00000000000000000000.index, deleting and rebuilding index...
...
2017-04-01 13:26:41,962 WARN kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread: [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-95], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@769e1ff5. Possible cause: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'responses': Error reading array of size 1204063, only 290 bytes available`

- Other normal broker nodes:

`[root@3 ~]# cd /var/local/kafka/
[root@3 kafka]# du --max-depth=1 -ch|sort -hr
48M total
48M ./data
48M .`


`[root@4 ~]# cd /var/local/kafka/
[root@4 kafka]# du --max-depth=1 -ch|sort -hr
48M total
48M ./data
48M .`

I am looking for why this caused?

Anybody has any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: try to add more details. What folders in ./data take space?

Comment: I have edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be due to multiple causes. It depends on your partitions and your process.

For instance, data is partionned by key, it means that all the records with the same key are processed in the same partition.

Comment: Yes ,you are right. I have forgotten to set the partitions.It is not right way to use kafka.